# what is better , WITH statement or left join 3 tables?

Tags: sql-server

Plz tell me what is better between 2 query in mssql ?

```
;with ab as (select a.*,b.CategoryName from Products a 
left join Categories b on a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID where b.CategoryID = 2)
select * from ab left join Suppliers c on ab.SupplierID = c.SupplierID
```

or

```
select * from Products a left join Categories b on a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
left join Suppliers c on a.SupplierID = c.SupplierID
where b.CategoryID = 2
```

Comment: are the same, WITH only help to make the code more readable.

Comment: Not enough info to tell.  You'd have to test both and "Better" is subjective.  I personally would do the 2nd one with the two left joins.  I only materialize the data in advance in extremely complex queries to simplify the maintenance.

Comment: The best way to compare them is to compare the execution plans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705. They'll tell you exactly how the query optimizer will execute the queries.

Answer (score 1):

are the same, `WITH` only help to make the code more readable.

You can test it  with EXPLAIN QUERY [How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)